# Meteor-accounts fails to log in

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using Meteor with the `accounts-password` package to design a login system. For a while it was working, but now it seems to have stopped with no noticeable cause. When I create an account, it takes a very long time (several minutes) for the callback to occur. If Meteor decides to re-render the page with an Ajax request in the middle, the account creation terminates with no callback. If it manages to complete without interruption, the callback comes back with an error saying the email already existed (it didn't), however the account is still created in the database. The user is not logged in as a result.

When I try to log in, the application hangs for several minutes as well but is either interrupted by an Ajax refresh or returns with Login Failed.

Comment: No other package added or change on the `Meteor.users` collection?

Comment: No, I've looked all over and nothing raises any red flags. The only account packages I have are `accounts-base` and `accounts-password`.

Comment: Is this happening locally? or on a *.meteor.com domain? Both?

Comment: Locally. I checked meteor update and everything is up to date.

Comment: Do you have any account validation code?

Comment: I really don't know, but I didn't set anything like that up. The last thing I did was add a very large database to my site. I'm using Nitrous and it doesn't say I'm maxing my ram out, but could that be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my server ran out of available RAM to process the request. I was using Nitrous.io and I hit my RAM limit. I removed my 25MB collection and the accounts system worked flawlessly. Adding the collection once again caused it to no longer work. This is with 1 GB of available RAM.